# A student takes a quiz (exam), a professor [verb]s a quiz, exam, etc

Tags: usage

I cannot seem to find an appropriate verb to use for a professor when he holds an exam, quiz, etc. so that students take it and get evaluated. Can we say a professor takes an exam? I suppose this is for the student side, right? Then, what is the verb for a professor?

Comment: I always need to think twice about this one, because in Spanish it is precisely the opposite: professors take the exam and students give it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct correlating verb for what a professor is doing whilst the students are taking the exam.

If the professor is overseeing the exam, making sure that the exam is being conducted properly, then he/she could be said to be **invigilating** at the exam; he/she is an **invigilator**.

She/he may be **invigiliating** at an exam that she/he has **set** and that his/her students are **taking**.

Comment: Note that invigilating will not be known to a speaker of American English. I've been heavily involved in academia over the years, and I've *never* heard it. Although it seems a perfect fit in this case, note that it is "chiefly British", so be mindful of this if you choose to use it.

Comment: Can't speak for my American friends, but invigilate/invigilator is pretty standard in Canada.

Comment: American English speaker here: I have never heard the word "invigilate" before in my life.  Fascinating, these differences between our "common" languages!

Comment: Same for proctor - in BE it's an officer as certain universities, mainly having  responsibilities for discipline.Not used in the context of overseeing exams etc at school level although may be used in higher education.

Answer (score 5):

The general term is ***administer***. This includes the entire process of scheduling, writing, and giving the exam.

> A professor *administers* an exam to her students.
>
> My professor *administered* an exam in our class yesterday.
>
> Are you going to *administer* that exam today?
>
> Dr. Thompson is *administering* an exam in Room 212; please be quiet!

Sometimes "administer" is also used to refer to the actual process of giving the exam, but technically, the correct term for this is ***proctor***. This would describe what the teacher is doing while the students are sitting and taking the exam.

> When I *proctor* exams, I always display a clock at the front of the room.
>
> Although Dr. Smith was supposed to be *proctoring* the chemistry exam, he was surfing the web instead!

In colloquial speech, you inevitably hear **give**. This works fine, and everyone will know what you are saying, but it is not quite as descriptive.

> I have to *give* an exam this afternoon to my Biology class.
>
> Dr. Brown is *giving* an exam this period, so he won't be able to have lunch with us.
>
> When the exam is *given*, will it include essay questions?
>
> When will we get grades for the exam that you *gave* last Thursday?

Comment: @Rompey I would say: "set an exam, then mark it".

Comment: @D.Nelson - Mark an exam is okay too, maybe it's [mostly used](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exam) in BrE

Comment: "Mark" is primarily British English, but it would *probably* be understandable to a speaker of American English. "Grade" and "score" are the common terms in American English.

Answer (score 2):

A professor **sets** an exam, then his students **take** the exam.

So the verb you were looking for is **set**.

Comment: So, can we say "Today, the professor set a very hard exam for us, and I estimate that half of the class will fail!"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Note, as an AmE speaker, I've never heard this term.

Comment: Using the verb "sets" implies "a date for", so the statement would be "The professor set a date for the exam." It doesn't make any sense for an abstract professor to set an exam, as you've phrased it here.

Comment: @Catija what would you use instead?

Comment: @CodyGray incorrect. The professor can both set the date, and also set the questions. If unspecified, "setting" the exam would normally refer to the latter.

Comment: Must be British English usage. I've never seen or heard this, would find it very confusing, and would circle it on an essay.

Comment: @CodyGray:  It is definitely used in British English - in fact "set" is exactly the word I thought of when I saw the question on the "Hot Network Questions".  I hadn't until now realized it wasn't used in all English dialects.

Comment: Exams are often set by an examination board; the board will probably not be present when the exam is taken and may or may not specify when the exam is to be held.